# Javascript - convert objects into array of object

Tags: javascript

I think it should be not hard but I just can't get it right.
I want to convert object:

```
{
{t1 : value1},
{t2 : value2},
{t3 : value3}
}
```

into array:

```
[
{t1 : value1},
{t2 : value2},
{t3 : value3}
]
```

How can I do it?

I tried:

```
let items = {{t1 : value1}, {t2 : value2}, {t3 : value3}}

let arr = items.map( obj => Object.values(obj) )
```

but got error:

> items.map is not a function

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Also, your original object is invalid. An object means every value is associated with a key.

Comment: `let items = [{t1 : value1}, {t2 : value2}, {t3 : value3}]`

Comment: This is an invalid object; i.e. you cannot have an object of objects without keys assigned to each of those objects.

Comment: Ensure your example is correct.  As @MMansour mentioned, this is not a valid syntax.  Either it's a block, with 3 unassigned objects, in which case you'd need to remove the commas, or it's an object without key/value pairs (only 3 nested objects)

Comment: We all saw that there is a problem with the object syntax, the original object is invalid. However, I also see that what @sooon really want to ask is how to iterates over all properties of an object and create an array based on all of those properties

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú I'm not sure we all do see that.  If that's the case, this question should be closed as that question has been asked before elsewhere.  I think the OP is confused on the structure and encountering errors that aren't related to what he's asking.  Once he understands how to format the object, then he will no longer have a question/problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const obj = {
   obj1: { t1: 'value1' },
   obj2: { t2: 'value2' },
   obj3: { t3: 'value3' }
}
let items = [];
for (var prop in obj) {
   items.push(obj[prop])
}
console.log(items)
```

I've corrected some syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to the `items`,because it's type is Object.When you use `Object.map`, and the error you have got is:

> items.map is not a function

Also you have another error on items, it just a **Object**.So it must have two elements —— `key` and `value`

Answer (score 0):

The object is invalid, try this:

> ```
> var obj = { KEY:{key: 'val'},...
> ```

Use `Object.keys()` which returns a real array, which in turn will be accepted by the array method `map()` to return the objects in an array.

### Demo

```js
var obj = {
  0: {
    key0: 'val0'
  },
  1: {
    key1: 'val1'
  },
  2: {
    key2: 'val2'
  }
};

var arrKeys = Object.keys(obj);

console.log(arrKeys);

var arrObj = arrKeys.map((key, idx) => {
  return obj[key];
});

console.log(arrObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an invalid object, Try this....

```js
let items = {  obj1: { t1: 'value1' },obj2: { t2: 'value2' },obj3: { t3: 'value3' }}
var result = Object.keys(items).map(function(key) {
  return [items[key]];
});

console.log(result);
```